# Can not access function's prototype's method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am going through JS the good parts and come to this example. In the last line I attempt to call upon a method that is defined in the prototype chain of the sum function. I am confused as to why this does not work.

Define the sum function:

```
var sum = function(){
    var i, sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i+=1){
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

add the method method to the function prototype

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
    this.prototype.name = func;
}
```

use the method method to add an 'add' method to sum

```
sum.method('add', function(a,b){
    return a + b;
})
```

The prototype method is clearly defined but I can not access it via the prototype chain:

```
sum.prototype.add(5,5); //returns 10
sum.add(5,5); //TypeError: sum.add not defined
```

In the last line why can I not access the method defined in the prototype chain of the sum function?

Comment: Well, your `method` function adds the function to `sum.prototype`, not to `sum`. *"defined in the prototype chain of the sum function"* No its not. The method is defined on `sum.prototype`. This property has nothing to do with sum's own prototype (which is `Function.prototype`: `Object.getPrototypeOf(sum) === Function.prototype`). You seem to confuse the prototype of the function with the prototype of instances of the function when called as constructor. Maybe read https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes ?

Comment: `this.prototype.name` should be `this.prototype[name]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: @Barmar: Potentially a typo? Otherwise `sum.prototype.add(5,5);` wouldn't work.

Comment: @FelixKling Not sure what you mean. I'm talking about the assignment `this.prototype.name = func`. He wants to use the value of the `name` parameter, not the literal name `name`.

Comment: @Barmar: Right. But in the last example they have `sum.prototype.add(5,5); //returns 10`. That wouldn't work if they had `this.prototype.name = func;` in their code, so I assume they actually use `this.prototype[name] = func;`.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sure the tutorial does it right. But it's wrong in the question, that's what my comment is about.

Answer (score 0):

`sum.prototype` has nothing to do with the prototype of the function. `sum.prototype` is the prototype of *instances* of `sum` when called as constructor (i.e. with `new`):

```
var instance = new sum(); // doesn't make sense, I know
Object.getPrototypeOf(instance) === sum.prototype; // true
instance.add // function
```

The prototype of `sum` itself can be accessed via `Object.getPrototypeOf(sum)` and is `Function.prototype`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(sum) === Function.prototype; // true
```

Btw, that's exactly why `sum.method()` works: You are extending `sum`'s prototype by assigning to `Function.prototype.method`.

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but extending functions via their prototype chain is probably not the right solution to your problem.

If you want to add a property to `sum`, then just assign it directly:

```
sum.add = function() { ... };
```